# How to set apache2 environment variables in wsgi file (Flask)

Tags: python, apache, flask, ubuntu-14.04

Currently I work with Flask micro framework.
How to set Environment variables in wsgi file?
I have done this in apache2 envvars file like this:

```
export PRODROOT=${PRODROOT:-/home/peter/Lv-164.UI/ecomap}
export PYSRCROOT=${PYSRCROOT:-${PRODROOT}/src/python}
export CONFROOT=${CONFROOT:-${PRODROOT}/etc}
export PYTHONPATH=${PRODROOT}/src/python
```

How I can do that in wsgi file?
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 5):

The wsgi file is just a Python file, so you can use `os.environ` to set environment variables for your code. E.g. in your wsgi file:

```
import os
os.environ['PRODROOT'] = '/home/peter/Lv-164.UI/ecomap'
os.environ['PYSRCROOT'] = os.environ['PRODROOT'] + '/src/python'
os.environ['CONFROOT'] = os.environ['PRODROOT'] + '/etc'
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = os.environ['PRODROOT'] + '/src/python'

from yourpackage.yourapp import app as application
```

I'm not sure that setting `PYTHONPATH` will work in this scenario (though it's worth a try). If you're using `mod_wsgi` then you can set it with the `WSGIPythonPath` directive.

https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath